# Probability Question ( Easy One )

Tags: probability

I really can't grasp probabilities.

So let's say we have 4 boxes. Each of these boxes has balls in it and ONLY 1 of them is black an the rest of the balls in a box are white.

The question is: What's the probability of picking all 4 balls if you have these amount of balls in the boxes:

- 1st box: 5 balls
- 2nd box: 11 balls
- 3rd box: 9 balls
- 4th box: 8 balls

Thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is there only one black ball in one of the boxes? Do we know which box this is (and how many balls it contains in total) or can it be any one of the four boxes?

Comment: Do you mean that each box has one black ball in it, and you want to know the probability of picking all four black balls?

Comment: Assuming you take 1 ball from each box, the prob they are all black is $1/(5\cdot11\cdot9\cdot8)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean: each box has only one black ball in it, you are picking one ball from each box, and you want to know the probability that all the four balls you pick are black.

In this case the answer is simply:

$$
\frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{11} \cdot \frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{3960}
$$

Comment: Thanks man , i'm really not good at probability